# problem on training(first epoch take a long time more than 4 hours )using colab and fastai

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

I have a problem on training (first epoch takes a long time more than 4 hours) using colab and fastai. It takes me about 5 hours only for the first epoch which is not useful using google colab because the limitation using of GPU 
I'm using  'efficientnet-b4' and about 52k training photos after data augmentation and 11k valid photos.

The problem is shown on the photo:

[image: Epoch training times]

Comment: Did you cache data on ram? So, 2nd epoch takes 19:31 minutes because of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Colab takes alot of time fetching the data from google drive as it is not indexed efficiently and thus makes the first epoch very long. For large datasets, I would recommend using google cloud storage and importing data from there.

Comment: are there any alternative ways other than Google Cloud Storage?